# Remote Event Receiver is not getting triggered from Quick Edit view

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, remote-event-receiver

I have adding , updating event on a list along with added and updated. Everything works fine with  new form and update form. But I switch to Quick edit , RER is not getting triggered. Is it something limitation on Quick edit? Any workaround on this. Added some part of business logic. So What I trying to achieve is based on user input , updating other fields. I am also pulling data from different list as well. So I can not replace this with calculated columns or any other out of box function.

```
    if ((properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["RandomColumn"].ToString() == null && !onEdit) || properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["RandomColumn"].ToString() == "")
    {
        result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("RandomColumn", "None");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using before after properties in RER?

Comment: Yes , using after properties.

Comment: Before-after properties will give you null in adding or added events in Office 365 in quick edit though it works like a charm in on-premise. If quick edit is not necessary then disable it.  Please provide your code or case scenario so one can help you or give workaround suggestion.

Comment: I will put code snippet in above question. So is it something limitation from Microsoft which says Quick Edit adding , after properties are null.

Answer (score 1):

Event Receiver will always trigger when we do inline editing for a list item.

> In ItemUpdating of my event receiver class, I am using
>   properties.AfterProperties['Field1'].But this 'Field1' column is not
>   visible in my inline editing that makes the return value as null
>   always and stops Aborting the event.
>
> To overcome this issue,i just call the properties.ListItem['Field1']
>   (because this value is not changed in inline editing) for returning
>   the actual value

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cc4b47e-1d3b-498c-bdc0-0ad1ec55f036/itemupdating-event-not-capturing-in-sharepoint-list-inline-editing?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).

> ItemAdding is event firing before list item is added, so at this time
>   SPListItem not exists yet. If you want to validate entered data, then
>   use properties.AfterProperties["FieldInternalName"]

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/03607763-8559-4f10-be5b-e1cc7e2e4d08/propertieslistitem-null-on-listitemadding-event-receiver?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Probably you were also doing the same mistake as I guess.

Comment: How about item adding ?

Comment: Yes its for both adding and updating - synchronous events.

Comment: properties.Listitem[] , Will it work for item adding as well ??

Comment: No, for item adding we will get Null because at this time SPLIstItem will not exists. I updated my answer

Comment: You can take some info from here: http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/

Comment: @DikeshGandhi as you stated , afterproperties does give null in Quick edit. So I can not use Adding event with it.